# Does OpenGL3+ admit a specific state to render 2D-only graphics?

Tags: opengl

I'm currently working on 2D graphics, and as far as I can tell every vertex is ultimately processed as a 4D point in homogeneous space. So I say to myself: what a waste of resources! I gather that the hardware is essentially designed to handle 3D scenes, and as such may be hardcoded to do 4d linear algebra. Yet, is there a way to write shaders (or enable a bunch of options) so that only genuine 2d coordinates are used in hard memory? I know one could embed two 2x2 matrices in a 4x4 matrix, but the `gl_Position` variable being a `vec4` seems to end the track here. I'm not looking for some kind of "workaround" hack like this, but rather of a canonical way to make OpenGL do it, like a specific mode/state.

I've not been able to find either sample code or even a simple mention of such a fact on the net, so I gather it should simply be impossible/not desirable for, say, performance reasons. Is that so?

Comment: Waaaaiitt...

You are working on 2D graphics, which are essentially using less resources anyway. This looks a lot like premature optimizations. And I think the answer will be "no" anyway because of how the rasterizer is built.

Comment: @Bartek I think it's still a valid question.  Even in a traditional 3D application you end up doing some things like HUDs that are completely 2D, so it's worth discussing the most efficient way to do it within OpenGL.

Comment: @NathanMonteleone It's not worth discussing it if a) it's not a real problem b) the proposed solution would improve it by such a tiny margin.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: My point exactly: it uses less memory on the CPU side, and also on the GPU side when I allocate memory and bind buffers. But the way the vertex shaders are usually written it seems to me that the output is 4D, and is then stored in that format for the rest of the pipelining procees. What if I have a lot of vertices (which is the case as I'm doing scientific computations), and don't necessarily want to optimize the samplings on the CPU size?

Comment: It doesn't imply using less/more memory on the CPU side. You can just fill up the missing values in the shader. `in vec2 position; void main() { gl_Position = vec4(position, 0, 1);` <- done. And I think you meant vertex shaders, because *fragment* shaders output colors typically. And if you are doing computations, you'd probably be better off using OpenCL (or compute shaders) instead.

Comment: Well of course I store only 2 floats instead of 4, and let the shader do the filling (and indeed I meant vertex shader, sorry). Yet I agree my question is only asked out of curiosity, I don't direly need that kind of optimization. I will if it's standard, though. As for using OpenCL & al, I'll consider this when I'm grown up enough ;)

Comment: Not really.
It's basically the same as saying they you only need to deal with numbers in the range 0-50 so is it inefficient to use a whole 32 bit int for the math? Well no. Because the hardware is there whether you use it or not.

Comment: @jcoder: I'm no hardware specialist, but I disagree that it is the same problem. Your memory is a lot of 32/64 bits cells, and you need twice as many to store 4 floats instead of just 2, which is what happens during the pipelining. I mean, that data is stored somewhere, and that somewhere is not made by *indivisible* cells of 4 float, right ?

Comment: I don't get it. You said yourself that you store pairs of floats, and you aren't *storing* anything when moving trough shaders. Your (imaginary) problem is completely unclear to me.

Comment: "… and you aren't storing anything when moving trough shaders." : that's maybe the part that is unclear to *me*. I thought that because at some point the GPU needs already processed data, say for Z-buffering or whatnot, that data was stored. I understand that if you disable Z-buffering then it might not be stored, but it isn't obvious (to me) that *nothing* is stored at all, since I don't master all the process. I apologize for having presented such an imaginary question, which I will undoubtely delete if you do think I'm making a fool of myself. Yet the storage was only *part* of my question.

Comment: … I was simply asking if OpenGL (and subsequent hardware) did admit a specific mode for dealing with 2D-graphics, is all.

Comment: The hardware likely is though. It can probably only read an process 4 floats at a time from memory.

Comment: @jcoder: right, then. As I said, I'm more on the abstract side of the moon ;)

Comment: Absolutely not. Hardware itself is/was designed around 4-component data and instructions for many years. Modern GPUs are scalar friendly, and they have to be considering the push for GPGPU (but older NV GPUs pre-GeForce 8xxx have a purely vector ALU). Now, as for vertex attributes, you get 16 slots of size (float * 4) for storage. This means whether you use a `vec2` or `vec4` vertex attribute, it actually behaves like a `vec4`. This can be seen if you ever write `vec4` and only give enough data for 2 of the components - GL automatically assigns **Z = 0.0** and **W = 1.0**.

Comment: Furthermore, you could not implement clipping in 2D space with 2D coordinates. You need homogeneous coordinates to produce NDC coordinates. You would need to use window space coordinates, which you cannot do from a vertex shader. After the vertex shader finishes, GL will perform clipping, perspective divide and viewport mapping to arrive at window space. But window space coordinates are still 4D (the Z component may not contribute to a location in window space, but it does affect fragment tests).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman : thank you, this is most helpful for me to understand what's going on. If you'd care to write your comment as an answer then I'd gladly accept it!

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier Sorry if I appeared too hostile. There's just way too many people that would spend a lot of time on useless "optimizations". In general, OpenGL is just an API and different platforms may behave *very differently*; thus you'd want to profile on every possible configuration you can get before you state "I have a problem with performance". And OpenCL really isn't that complicated; it is designed ground up for computations and isn't meant to be hard (what would be the point of that?).

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: it's all right, I'm used to heated discussions ;) My point was that I was seeking a standard way of doing things properly, I wasn't after some epsilon optimization. So the answer is : there is none, for all the good reasons everybody mentionned. Your comments helped me to amend my question and to think more clearly about what I meant. The question was after all not trivial as the answer lied in the hardware configuration of GPUs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All credit goes to  Andon M. Coleman, who perfectly answered the question as a comment. I just quote it here for the sake of completion:

«Absolutely not. Hardware itself is/was designed around 4-component data and instructions for many years. Modern GPUs are scalar friendly, and they have to be considering the push for GPGPU (but older NV GPUs pre-GeForce 8xxx have a purely vector ALU). Now, as for vertex attributes, you get 16 slots of size (float * 4) for storage. This means whether you use a `vec2` or `vec4` vertex attribute, it actually behaves like a `vec4`. This can be seen if you ever write vec4 and only give enough data for 2 of the components - GL automatically assigns `Z = 0.0` and `W = 1.0`.

Furthermore, you could not implement clipping in 2D space with 2D coordinates. You need homogeneous coordinates to produce NDC coordinates. You would need to use window space coordinates, which you cannot do from a vertex shader. After the vertex shader finishes, GL will perform clipping, perspective divide and viewport mapping to arrive at window space. But window space coordinates are still 4D (the Z component may not contribute to a location in window space, but it does affect fragment tests). »

Answer (score 1):

Modern GPUs are actually scalar architectures. In GLSL you can write also shorter vectors. `vec2` is a perfectly valid type and you can create vertex arrays with just 2 scalar elements per vector, as defined by the `size` parameter of [glVertexAttribPointer](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml)

As Anon M. Coleman commented, OpenGL will internally perform a `vec4(v, [0, [0]], 1)` construction for any data passed in as a vertex attribute of dimension < 4.

In the vertex shader you must assign a `vec4` to `gl_Position`. But you can trivially expand a `vec2` to a `vec4`:

```
vec2 v2;
gl_Position = vec4(v2, 0, 1);
```

Yes, the `gl_Position` output always must be a `vec4`, due to the fact OpenGL specifies operations in clip space. But this is not really a bottleneck at all.

Comment: GL already does this automatically if you declare a vertex attribute as `vec4` in GLSL and then use `glVertexAttribPointer (...)` with `size`=2 (z = **0.0**, w = **1.0**). Since a `vec2` vertex attribute takes as many slots as a `vec4` (1), you can effectively treat any attribute smaller than a `vec4` as if it were a `vec4` just by declaring it that way in the shader. You will not save any memory by changing the declaration in the shader alone, but you definitely can save memory by using a vertex buffer with only 2 components and letting GL expand the missing components for you.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: I'll add that. But my original intention was to show, how a vec2 would be properly assigned to gl_Position.

Comment: @datenwolf: thanks for your answer. but I'm afraid it doesn't answer my question. Actually I did know how to expand vec2->vec4 (though I ignored it was done automatically), my question was whether the standard (and hardware) has a dedicated mode for 2D.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier: The OpenGL specification: No. And modern GPUs are scalar architectures, i.e. when you program using `vec2` they consume less memory bandwidth and can pack more instructions into their pipeline; thus I'd answer with a "weak" yes. But why do you care? This is such a insignificant thing to try optimize. When it comes to performance you should reduce the consumed memory bandwidth, i.e. the amount of data in the VBO. Computationally it makes little difference.

Comment: @datenwolf : I agree to all this, as explained in the (rather long) discussion in the coments to the question. In particular I'm *not* looking for optimization. but only I wanted to be sure of using the right OpenGL state for my work… In that respect Andon M. Coleman answered me pretty well in his comments.